# ASP.NET MVC - JQuery datepicker format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a form that accepts employee's date of birth and I have used jquery datepicker ui for that. I want the date picker to use the 'dd-mm-yyyy' format. any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.DOB)
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#DOB').datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify the dateformat as below

```
$('#DOB').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy' })
```

Comment: thanks. I tried datepicker({dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy'}) and it worked..

Comment: Welcome :-)  Kindly accept the answer and request you to google before asking questions.

Comment: Agreed with @Santosh. Not only would Google have quickly turned up an answer, but there's at least three related SO questions just in the sidebar that would have given you answer. Please also pay attention to existing questions when creating a new one. SO shows you dupes automatically as you're typing your title.